# How to tell when a UITableView section index letter is tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

In iOS, is there a delegate method that is called when the section index of a table view is tapped? For instance, if the table's section index lists the letters A-Z and B is tapped, how can I determine what letter the user tapped? I've looked throughout the documentation but am unable to find anything.

Comment: +1. I initially downvoted because I assumed this was an obvious delegate method in the docs, but bizarrely, it's not there!

Comment: Thanks for checking. :) Yeah, I'm pretty flummoxed. You'd think it'd be pretty easy.

Comment: @capitallt Can I ask why you want to do this? What do you want to do other than scrolling to that section as it already does?

Comment: I want to add a HUD with the letter in it when the user swipes along the section index. Remember the old iPod classics, when you'd spin fast enough that it would start jumping from letter to letter and would show a black and white hud with the capitalized letter for the section. Just some nice feedback for the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delegate which allows you do determine when a section index letter is tapped. However, you can still do so fairly easily.

If we use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` `scrollViewDidScroll` to set a breakpoint, we can get pretty close to when the user taps the index and see what messaging we might be able to take advantage of. Here's a look at the frames directly after the user taps the index:

```
frame #1: UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 56
frame #2: UIKit`-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 645
frame #3: UIKit`-[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 362
frame #4: UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _setContentOffset:animated:animationCurve:animationAdjustsForContentOffsetDelta:] + 669
frame #5: UIKit`-[UITableView _sectionIndexChangedToIndex:title:] + 285
frame #6: UIKit`-[UITableView _sectionIndexChanged:] + 189
```

So, `UITableView` has a private method `_sectionIndexChanged`. In addition after the index has changed, the `UITableView` internals call `setContentOffset`. Either of these could be used to provide a mechanism to determine when a section index is tapped.

If I were doing this I would likely subclass `UITableView` to intercept `_sectionIndexChanged` and extend the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to provide the needed messages. Alternately, you could subclass `UITableView` and intercept `setContentOffset`, but that would require taking care of corner cases where `setContentOffset` is called without the index being tapped.

Comment: Subclassing UITableView and overriding a private method sounds like it might work, but I think it would carry some rejection risk. Or, baring that, risk of breakage across OS updates.

Comment: @JesseRusak Of course. The OP is asking to do something that isn't possible without rolling your own tableView from scratch or a bit of swizzling. I leave it up to the OP to determine if his use case makes it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two reasonable solutions which could work for your goal.

First, you could override the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` to show and update the HUD if the offset has changed. Of course, this will cause it to appear when the user scrolls without the index. You can prevent the majority of these cases by simply disabling the display of the HUD when the scroll views's `dragging` or `decelerating` property is YES. There will still be some cases where the HUD will appear (e.g. scrollToTop, resizing) but this might be acceptable to you.

The other option is to just build your own index control. It really wouldn't be a lot of work to lay out a few labels inside a custom view along the right-hand side of your table view with a couple of gesture recognizers. Then you can scroll the table view and display whatever HUD you want.

Comment: +1. Another solution: you could subclass `UITableView` and override the `touchesBegan:…` methods to detect where a user's finger is. This would allow you to only display the HUD when the user's finger is along the right side of the table view. (You might not even need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`.)